# Elasticsearch sort: by one from each group and repeat

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I need to get items with max `value` from each `name` and repeat until end.

I'll explain it on simple example. I have such items:

```
Name| Value
-----------
AAA | 12
AAA | 35
AAA | 5
BBB | 1
BBB | 10
BBB | 5
```

Expected result after sort:

```
Name| Value
-----------
AAA | 35
BBB | 10
AAA | 12
BBB | 5
AAA | 5
BBB | 1
```

I know how to do it in Postgres (window functions: `rank() over()`), but is it possible in Elastic?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If it is, I would be interested to see a working solution that doesn't involve post-processing of the results.

Comment: @AndreiStefan postprocessing is not acceptable on large datasets

Comment: What is the use case here? Do you do frequent updates to documents? How is the "real-time" factor? (do you need the updates/new documents visible in results right away?) How much data is involved here?

Comment: @AndreiStefan use case is next: show one most recent(index=1) product from each category, than most recent(index=2) from each category with same category order ... until all products ends. For example: prod1_cat1, prod1_cat2, prod1_cat3, prod2_cat1, prod2_cat2, prod2_cat3, etc.
It is some kind of controlled products balancing (to show products from all categories). 
More than 1 million records. Everything must be in real time.

Comment: Showing >1 million records is a bad idea no matter how those documents are sorted, when it comes to Elasticsearch. My questions were asked to see how appropriate is to create a second ES index with the results of probably 1 query + post processing and holding something like "first 1000 records" (meaning a human reasonable list of documents) and to update that list periodically (every 10 seconds or so). You could use Watcher to build this index and keep it updated. 1 million records, as I said, is both impractical (who would look at 1mil docs) and not performant from ES point of view.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I didn't say I will show all records on 1 page. Pagination is for that. And 1000 recent records is not working with different filters. Yes, I understand how to actualize index in case of new records added, but the question is about dynamic sorting. Because actualizing can be very difficult operation for such a big elastic index.

Comment: What I'm saying is to keep a separate index which should include only first 1000 documents that are sorted according to your requirements. And this index is updated regularly, not your main one with 1mil documents. Regarding pagination and 1 mil. documents... how many pages do you believe your users will go through?! 10, 15, 20? Not even google.com is giving you everything. Only few tens of pages, even though there can be hundreds of millions of matches. Keep in mind that Elasticsearch is a search engine, not a database. The aim is to give you the best matching docs, not all of them.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes, I understand that. But as I wrote in previous response there are different filters that can exclude 99.9% records from result. And I need to correctly sort that 0.1% (1K records, for example) that can be gathered from all index, not only from 1K-10K recent ones.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand my workaround. With Watcher you could run a query and then post-process the results and index them into another index. This query will run over **all the documents in your main index**. It will aggregate the documents according to your requirements (I think a `terms` aggregation on `Name`, ordered by `Value`), you can add a post-processing step to create the order you need and then index that into a second index. Next time the watch will trigger, it will delete the old index, perform the same query again and index the new results in the (now empty) index.

Comment: But, anyway, as I said, really interested in seeing a solution to this, if there is one. Without post-processing and only running one query.

Comment: How about running a multi-search query (one for each category sorted by value) and then merging the hits from the responses you get, sort of like a zipper.

Comment: Actually I don't see `repeat value` in your expected result, looks like you expect to see `35` for all `AAA` ?

Answer (score 1):

> You have to do something like Group by max

Here is Example

```
GET /yourindex/_search
{
"size": 0
  "aggs": {
    "yourGroup": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "theMax": {
          "max": {
            "field": "Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Reference:-** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284125/how-to-do-group-by-max-query)

Comment: Group by max, but how do you make sure one result comes from one terms agg, next comes from another terms and so on. And then start over with the next results from each agg again? Have you actually tested the proposed solution?

Comment: not sure how this solves the problem, the solution is much more involved than a simple aggregation. See the other answer by @AndreiStefan

Comment: This doesnt solve the original problem. It only returns counts of different groups. 
The questions says - results should have one item per group and the order itself should repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregating here my comments.

To answer your direct question: no, not possible to my knowledge. But there are workarounds where Elasticsearch could help.

Showing >1 million records is a bad idea no matter how those documents are sorted, when it comes to Elasticsearch. My questions in comments were asked to see how appropriate is to create a second ES index with the results of probably **1 query + post processing and holding something like "first 1000 records" (meaning a human reasonable list of documents) and to update that list periodically (every 10 seconds or so).** You could use **Watcher** to build this index and keep it updated. 1 million records, as I said, is both impractical (who would look at 1mil docs) and not performant from ES point of view.

Basically, keep a **separate index** which should include only first 1000 documents that are sorted according to your requirements. And this index is updated regularly, not your main one with 1 mil documents. Regarding pagination and 1 mil. documents... how many pages do you believe your users will go through?! 10, 15, 20? Not even google.com is giving you everything. Only few tens of pages, even though there can be hundreds of millions of matches. Keep in mind that Elasticsearch is a **search engine, not a database. The aim is to give you the best matching docs, not all of them.**

The query from Watcher will run over all the documents in your main index. It will aggregate the documents according to your requirements (I think a `terms` aggregation on `Name`, ordered by `Value`), you can add a [post-processing step](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.2/transform.html) to create the order you need and then [index that into a second index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.2/actions-index.html). Next time the watch will trigger, it will delete the old index, perform the same query again and index the new results in the (now empty) index.

Comment: Sounds like the most logical approach to me too

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch supports sorting by array or multi-valued fields. The mode option controls what array value is picked for sorting the document it belongs to. The mode option can have the following values:

`min` -- Pick the lowest value.

`max` -- Pick the highest value.

`sum` -- Use the sum of all values as sort value. Only applicable for number based array fields.

`avg` -- Use the average of all values as sort value. Only applicable for number based array fields.

`median` -- Use the median of all values as sort value. Only applicable for number based array fields.

**Sort Order:**
The order option can have the following values:

`asc` -- Sort in ascending order

`desc` -- Sort in descending order

Below is a example in which field price has multiple prices per document. In this case the result hits will be sorted by price descending based on the average price per document.

```
PUT /my_index/_doc/1?refresh
{
   "product": "chocolate",
   "price": [20, 4]
}

POST /_search
{
   "query" : {
      "term" : { "product" : "chocolate" }
   },
   "sort" : [
      {"price" : {"order" : "desc", "mode" : "avg"}}
   ]
}
```

**Nested sorting example**
In the below example offer is a field of type nested. The nested path needs to be specified; otherwise, Elasticsearch doesn’t know on what nested level sort values need to be captured.

```
POST /_search
{
   "query" : {
      "term" : { "product" : "chocolate" }
   },
   "sort" : [
       {
          "offer.price" : {
             "mode" :  "avg",
             "order" : "asc",
             "nested": {
                "path": "offer",
                "filter": {
                   "term" : { "offer.color" : "blue" }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

Please refer this link [Elastic search sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html) for detailed explanation and much more examples.